# mysql select order by começando pela data de hoje

Tags: mysql, data, order-by, order

Tenho essa consulta que busca aniversários do mês:

```
$mesHoje = date("m");
$sqlAni = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM aniversario WHERE MONTH(dia) = :mesHoje ORDER BY dia ASC');
$sqlAni->execute(array("mesHoje" => $mesHoje));
```

Como fazer para ordenar pelo dia de hoje? Exemplo (hoje é dia 23), então as datas abaixo:

```
07/10/1928
12/10/1987
15/10/2012
24/10/1942
30/10/1999
```

Ficariam nessa ordem (repare que a primeira data é dia 24, pois é a data mais próxima de hoje, que é dia 23):

```
24/10/1942
30/10/1999
07/10/1928
12/10/1987
15/10/2012
```

Não posso levar em consideração o ano, apenas o dia.

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você quer dizer com "ordenar pelo dia de hoje". Se você quer ordenar pelo dia,  pode ordenar pelo dia do mês em ordem ascendente ou decrescente.

Comment: Quero ordenar pelo dia, mas PRECISO que o primeiro dia seja o mais próximo com o dia atual (HOJE). Deixei mais claro no exemplo.

Comment: Testei a resposta da pergunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186962/sql-query-to-show-nearest-date e funcionou. Da uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caio a forma que conheço para isso é utilizando **FIND_IN_SET**

A estrutura de teste que criei foi essa:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Local` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Local` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COR` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='    ';

INSERT INTO tbl_Local
VALUES (1,  "A",    "RED",  "2018-10-10"),
 (2,    "A",    "RED",  "2018-10-12"),
 (3,    "B",    "RED",  "2018-10-05"),
 (4,    "B",    "BLACK",    "2018-10-23"),
 (5,    "B",    "WHITE",    "2018-10-28"),
 (6,    "C",    "RED",  "2018-10-30"),
 (7,    "D",    "BLUE", "2018-10-01"),
 (8,    "E",    "BLUE", "2018-10-05"),
 (9,    "E",    "ORANGE",   "2018-10-06"),
 (10,   "E",    "YELLOW",   "2018-10-13"),
 (11,   "E",    "RED",  "2018-10-22"),
 (12,   "F",    "RED",  "2018-10-21"),
 (13,   "G",    "ORANGE",   "2018-10-18"),
 (14,   "G",    "BLUE", "2018-10-04"),
 (15,   "H",    "ORANGE",   "2018-10-02")
```

E a sintaxe SQL:

```
Select * from tbl_Local ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(DAY(DATA), '23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22')
```

A função **FIND_IN_SET** ou (**FIND** se preferir) esta sendo utilizada para criar uma lista a partir de um critério que coloquei ( no caso a lista estática começando no dia 23)
A única questão é a seguinte. Não existe ( eu pelo menos não conheço) alguma forma dessa lista vir dinâmica para o dia atual e a partir dai ir seguindo para os próximos dias.

O que aconselho é você passar essa lista como uma string já montada em sua aplicação e montar a sua sintaxe sql dinamicamente

Algo como mais ou menos isso:

```
$mesHoje = date("m");
$diaHoje = date("d");
$recebeArrayDia = "";
for ($iDia = $diaHoje; $iDia <= 31; $iDia++) {
    $recebeArrayDia .= $iDia.",";
}
for ($iDia = 1; $iDia < $diaHoje; $iDia++) {
    $recebeArrayDia .= $iDia.",";
}
$recebeArrayDia = substr_replace($recebeArrayDia, "", -1);
$sqlAni = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM aniversario WHERE MONTH(dia) = :mesHoje ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(DAY(dia), :recebeArrayDia)');
$sqlAni->execute(array("mesHoje" => $mesHoje, "recebeArrayDia" => $recebeArrayDia));
```

Segue link para o

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ad945/1)

Comment: Não tinha pensado dessa forma, funcionou, valeu!